# how to hardcode the lookupedit

Tags: c#, devexpress

hii,,
I am using c# in my windows application i need to hardcode the lookupedit..I want the lookupedit to show"YES"when the value member is 1 and "NO"when the value member is 0..

Right now when i am using lookupedit,it is showing all the display members.that is all yes and no's...this dont want to happen.I just need one yes and no option just like combo box...please help me

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your task correctly, you should filter the LookupEdit's underlying DataSource so that it contains only two records with ValueMember equals 0 and 1.